# If ID from db row matches id from PHP GET function, return x page

Tags: php, database, mysqli

basically I want to display a row from my database when the id from a `get id` switch statement matches the id from said row in the database. I'm confusing myself here so let me explain further.

If the url is `www.example.com/index.php?id=2`
I want the row with the id of 2 to be displayed on the page.

Here is an example of what is in the database;

`id = 2`
`name = john`
`id = 3`
`name = mark`

So if the id in the URL is equal to 2, then display id 2 and name john.
But if the id in the URL is equal to 3, then display id 3 and name mark.

I'm using a get function to do this but I'm not sure how to basically get the two ids to compare themselves and get the respective row from the database.

I'm quite new to PHP as well, so small words please! :)

---

Revision 2.

Like I said above, I'm new to PHP so a lot of what has been posted is confusing me a lot. But when I'm trying out various bits of code, I'm getting the following;

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given ...
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
```

I've used each sample of code, but it seems like I'm mixing them now. Hmm.

Comment: Show your code. What did you try yourself?

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM names");

$getid = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id FROM names");

$id = mysqli_fetch_array($getid);

switch ($_GET['id'] = $id) {

 case $id : include("./assets/style/temps/blog_body.php");
 
break;

}`

Does that help? The formatting on here is tricky.

Comment: please put that in an update of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this (database connection code and error handling not shown):

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id=$id");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['id']." ".$row['name'];
```

About the posted code:

1. You never use `$result`.
2. Inside your `switch`, you are assigning `$id` to `$_GET['id']`, which results to using the `include` always, except when `$_GET['id']` is 0.

Comment: An example that doesn't use prepared statement is a shame.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing here. Would that get the info from the database and display row 4 if the id was equal to 4 for example? I want to be able to put an id (a number) in the url and have a different name show on the page.

Comment: Yes. That is what the `WHERE` part in the query does. It only gets one single row.

Comment: I'm now getting what I've edited in my original question at the bottom of it at the top of my page when I use your code. It's referring to line 2 and 3 in your code above.

Comment: Fixed it, I was missing $mysqli out of the second line (from your code above). Works now, thank you!

Comment: @Red no problem, good luck in learning PHP! Do read the documentation and experiment a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the **id** value to your sql( by maintaining sql injection threat) and then you can get the values of the fetched  by using fetch_assoc function of mysql(deprecated) or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM names where id='$id'"); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
$row_id = $row['id'];

header("www.example.com/index.php?id=$row_id");
```

Warning! This is just a simple answer. There are many DANGERS of using this code as it is wide open for SQL injection attacks. Consider sanitation (eg. intval($_GET['id']). And header() function is used by assuming not header information is sent before this code (even space!).

Comment: I know @YourCommonSense, but Red is stuck in a very basic problem for which I thought he needs just a way forward!

Answer (score 0):

You should use **prepared statments**. Here is an example using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stm->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$name = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Even though it is "more correct" than my answer, it might go way over the head of the OP. He is even struggling in getting a basic `switch` statement correct.